# One field assigned null when deserialising JSON with Jackson in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm calling an external API using Spring `restTemplate`. The returned JSON has the following content.

```
{
  "message": null,
  "responseStatus": "0",
  "accessInfo": {
    "access": {
      "message": "success",
      "token": {
        "expires": "xxxxx",
        "id": null,
        "UDID": null,
        "permissions": {
          "orgGroups": [],
          "channelGroups": [
            "xxxxx"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "profile": {
    "message": null,
    "responseStatus": null,
    "UDID": "xxxxx",
    "name": null,
    "age": null,
    "gender": null,
    "maritalStatus": null,
    "familySize": null,
    "lat": null,
    "lon": null,
    "birthDay": null,
    "imageURL": null,
    "sessionId": "xxxxx",
    "FBId": null,
    "expiry": null,
    "email": "xxxxx",
    "workLocationLat": null,
    "workLocationLong": null,
    "workLocationAddress": null,
    "homeLocationAddress": null,
    "homeLocationLat": null,
    "homeLocationLong": null,
    "id": 789,
    "isFBIdAlreadyExists": false,
    "tagList": []
  }
}
```

All the values are really what is returned except for those `xxxxx` which I masked. As you can see, there are two `UDID` fields in the JSON. One is in the node `accessInfo` > `access` > `token` which is `null` and the other in the node `profile`. The value in the second node is the one I'm interested in which is not supposed to be `null`.

I have created 2 POJOs as given below. I'm only interested in `UDID` and `sessionId` under `profile` node.

Parent POJO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AgtAuthentication {

    private Profile profile;

}
```

Child POJO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Profile {

    private String sessionId;
    private String UDID;

}
```

I have removed the getters and setters and no args constructors for brevity.

When I call the Api I receive the response and the JSON mapping works fine except for the `UDID` attribute. When I do a `System.out.println()` for the response body, I get the below result:

```
Authentication [profile = Profile [sessionId = xxxxx, UDID = null]]
```

`sessionId` is correct. However, `UDID` is always `null`. Not sure if this is because there's a duplicate `UDID` value in the JSON. Can anyone help? Thanks.

EDIT: The code that calls the actual Api (`xxxxx` being masked values) is below:

```
private void setUuidAndSessionId() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        requestBody.add("clientId", "xxxxx");
        requestBody.add("clientPassword", "xxxxx");
        requestBody.add("UDID", "");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(requestBody, headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String agtAuthUrl = "http://xxxxx";

        ResponseEntity<AgtAuthentication> response = restTemplate.exchange(agtAuthUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, AgtAuthentication.class);

        System.out.println(response.getBody().toString());

        sessionId = response.getBody().getProfile().getSessionId();
        String tempUuid = response.getBody().getProfile().getUDID();
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the code with the restTemplate?

Comment: @XavierBouclet added the `restTemplate` code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming Jackson expects a field in the JSON named `uDID` - because of getter/setter method naming convention converting the first letter of field to uppercase.

You can try to annotate the `Profile.getUDID()` getter with `@JsonProperty("UDID")`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks man. I added the property on the attribute itself. Hope that's okay.